# Vue3 - Getting next item from object - value not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to let my users go through an object that contains different items.

Example of `records` object:

```json
0: {id: 1, pipeline_id: 1, raw: '1', completion: null, processed: 0, …}
1: {id: 2, pipeline_id: 1, raw: '2', completion: null, processed: 0, …}
2: {id: 3, pipeline_id: 1, raw: '3', completion: null, processed: 0, …}
3: {id: 4, pipeline_id: 1, raw: '4', completion: null, processed: 0, …}
4: {id: 5, pipeline_id: 1, raw: '5', completion: null, processed: 0, …}
```

I am using Vue3 and [Collect.js](https://collect.js.org/api/slice.html) like below:

```js
const props = defineProps({
    records: {
        type: Object,
    },
});

let currentRecord = collect(props.records).first();

const nextRecord = () => {
    // Set "currentRecord" to the next item in the "records" array.
    currentRecord = collect(props.records).slice(props.records.indexOf(currentRecord) + 1).first();

    console.log(currentRecord)
}
```

The users can shuffle through the array using the `nextRecord` method:

```html
<textarea v-model="currentRecord.raw"></textarea>

<a @class="nextRecord">Skip Record</a>
```

The above code successfully changes the currentRecord in the `console.log`, but not in the `<textarea>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `currentRecordIndex` initialized with `0` and increment it using the click event handler and use `computed` property to return the `currentRecord` :

```js
import {computed,ref} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
    records: {
        type: Object,
    },
});
let currentRecordIndex =ref(0)
let currentRecord = computed(()=>collect(props.records).slice(currentRecordIndex.value).first());

const nextRecord = () => {
   currentRecordIndex.value++;
}
```